# When sending a GraphQL Get Request Receiving a 400 Error

Tags: graphql, insomnia

I am using the Insomnia client to form GraphQL Queries. 
I have the following Query
`query purchaseOrders{purchaseOrders(limit: 1){poNumber}}`

Sending with the Bearer Token as the only header.

I'm getting a `400` response,  this is the first time I've worked with GraphQL, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to troubleshoot.

This Query works in my sandbox.

Comment: GraphQL usually responds with 400 if the query is malformed or does not conform to the schema. Without more context it is hard to help you. Do you use a public API or a private one?

Comment: This is the API for Wayfair.  I am working with the GraphiQL builder, and Insomnia GraphQL Client.  The query works in GraphiQL sandbox, but not when I try to send it from Insomnia.

Comment: Do they have a public API URL (the URL you put into Insomnia) or developer page (as in clickable link for me) that I could have a look at for you? Generally when asking for help here you will receive maximum support when you make it as easy as possible for people to help you :)

Comment: @Herku I dont think they have a public development site, I have to login to their partners portal to get to the schema and testing tools.  Is there anything else I can supply to help you help me?  This is my first experience with GraphQL, and I dont know what I dont konw.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the API isn't in production yet.